# PowerPoint (pptx) in iOS

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, powerpoint

I am trying to embed a pptx presentation that contains videos and animations in a iOS native app.

`UIWebView` - it renders it, you can scroll trough the slides, but there is no actual interaction with the slides (ex: clicking on a button that sends you on a certain slider, etc).

I've tried to convert the pptx to a HTML format (mht and normal html format - both fail miserably) with powerpoint2003 (later versions don't suport conversion to html format anymore).

I have to mention that it's a single powerpoint presentation with many slides, so the app will be static, containing only the presentation and the content won't change.

I don't know what to try next. I was thinking to convert to HTML5 (if there is any way to convert pptx to html5). I don't have any ideas left - except making a native app from scratch that simulates the way the pptx looks and works.

Comment: "making a native app from scratch that simulates the way the pptx looks and works." sounds like the way to go. imho.

Comment: agreed on @ade's comment. An app that simply contains a webpage will not get though the App Store review. For user experience you should make it a native app, it might not be that hard. Basically you export your power point slides as images, put them together with UIScrollView or UIPageViewController, and add the interaction you like.

Comment: But it's a big powerpoint. And has a lot of interaction features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to HTML5 then embed in UIWebView is the answer. To retain interactions is difficult. But you don't have to reinvent the wheel, a tool called SlideGo is available and free. It also exposes some javascript API if you need to build your own navigation, otherwise just use default swiping to advance slides.